# cakephp3 プラグインの読み込みができない

Tags: cakephp, composer, mamp

OS: OS X Yosemite
AP, DB, 言語: MAMP（Apache 2.2.29, MySQL 5.5.42, PHP 5.6.10）
フレームワーク: CakePHP 3.2.1
パッケージ管理ツール: Composer

http://yamabe.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/06/06/235854
上記のブログを参考にBootstrap3を導入しようと思ったのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

[image: エラー内容]
自身のコントローラで以下を記述しました。

```
class UimagesController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = [
        'Html' => [
            'className' => 'Bootstrap3.BootstrapHtml'
        ],
        'Form' => [
            'className' => 'Bootstrap3.BootstrapForm'
        ],
        'Paginator' => [
            'className' => 'Bootstrap3.BootstrapPaginator'
        ],
        'Modal' => [
            'className' => 'Bootstrap3.BootstrapModal'
        ]
    ];
```

bootstrap.php内では、

```
Plugin::load('Bootstrap3');
Plugin::loadAll();
```

ともに記述してあります。

composer.json内では

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.1",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
    "holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers": "dev-master"
},
```

composer update した結果は以下になります。

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers instead.
Generating autoload files
> Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump
```

何か助言をいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: プログラムコードは半角スペースを全角に変換せず、専用の書式 (先頭に半角空白4文字) を使って記載してください。洗濯してエディタの「{}」アイコンをクリックしても同じことができます。

Comment: 助言ありがとうございます。

Comment: そのプラグインのインストール（composer.jsonの修正＆composer update）は行いましたか？

Comment: 追記しました。いずれも行いました。

Comment: エラーメッセージに `Package holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers instead.` とあって、`holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers` ではなく `holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers` を使えということのようですが、これは関係ありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ php composer.phar require holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers:dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers instead.
Generating autoload files
> Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump
```

を行った結果、「holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers」というものが出てきたので、それをcomposerによってインストールすることができました。